# Prove that the support function satisfies $\sigma_{A+B}=\sigma_A+\sigma_B$ for $A,B$ compact convex sets

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, support-function

Let $A, B, C$ be compact convex sets in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $A + C = B + C$.
The purpose of this problem is to prove that $A = B$. Define the support
function
$$\sigma _A (x) := \max\{\langle x, u\rangle : u ∈ A\}.$$
(a) Show that $\sigma _A$ is a convex function defined for all $x ∈ R ^n$ .

## Proof

Observe:
$\sigma_A((1-t)x+ty)=\max\{\langle(1-t)x+ty,u\rangle:u \in A\}=\max\{\langle(1-t)x,u\rangle+\langle ty,u\rangle :u \in A\}\leq \max\{\langle(1-t)x,u\rangle :u \in A\}+\max\{\langle ty,u \rangle :u \in A\}=(1-t)\sigma_A(x)+t\sigma_A(y)$

---

(b) Show that $$\sigma_{A+B}=\sigma_A +\sigma_B$$

I need help with part (b).

Comment: I need help with part b

Comment: Hint: Fix $x$. By compactness you know there is a $u^* \in A$ such that $\sigma_A(x) = <x,u^*>$.  Similar for $\sigma_B(x)$ and $\sigma_{A+B}(x)$.  Also, you might try first showing $\leq$ and then $\geq$.

Comment: I'm not understanding your hint @Michael

Comment: I would love to see the solution when you get it

Comment: Can you explain the difficulty?  What is blocking you from finishing the argument?  Can you prove at least one direction (i.e., either $\leq$ or $\geq$)?

Comment: $\sigma_B(x)=<x,u*> and \sigma_{A+B}(x)=<x,u*>  $? Im not understanding what you mean when you first show $\leq$ then $\geq$ @Michael

Comment: Why did you write what you did?  Why are you using $u^*$ for both $\sigma_B$ and $\sigma_{A+B}$?  I mean first show $\sigma_{A+B}(x)\leq \sigma_A(x) + \sigma_B(x)$, then the reverse inequality.  You need to have basic understanding of what a "maximum over a set" means to solve this problem. If you don't understand what a maximum over a set is, you will not be able to appreciate a full proof hand delivered to you.

Comment: Oooo that makes sense . Let me look at this some more  @Michael

Comment: Let $C=\{<x,u>:u \in A\}$ , $D=\{<x,u>:u \in B\}$ and fix $x \in R^{n}$. We have $z \leq \sigma_{A}(x) \forall z \in C$ and $y \leq \sigma_{B}(x) \forall z \in D$. Hence we have $z+y \leq \sigma_{A}(x)+\sigma_{B}(x) \forall z \in C, y\in D$. Hence we have$ \sigma_{A+B}=max_{z \in C, y \in D} z+y \leq \sigma_A(x)+\sigma_B(x)$ @Michael

Comment: Is it something like this

Answer (score 0):

Let $C=\{<x,u>:u \in A\}$ , $D=\{<x,u>:u \in B\}$ and fix $x \in R^{n}$. We have $z \leq \sigma_{A}(x) \forall z \in C$ and $y \leq \sigma_{B}(x) \forall z \in D$. Hence we have $z+y \leq \sigma_{A}(x)+\sigma_{B}(x) \forall z \in C, y\in D$. Hence we have$ \sigma_{A+B}=max_{z \in C, y \in D} z+y \leq \sigma_A(x)+\sigma_B(x)$